# Selenium and Python - How to click submit button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

This is the source code of the webpage ( https://eu.luxpowertek.com/WManage/web/login ) I am trying to login in and click the submit button.

```
<div id="loginFormContainer" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 450px; position: relative;">
    <form id="loginHolder" action="/WManage/web/login" method="post">
        <h2 class="title" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0;">
            Monitor Center
        </h2>
        <div class="form-horizontal" style="padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 45px;"><img src="https://resource.solarcloudsystem.com/WManage/web/img/format/icons/user.png?v=2.0.4.4" height="16" /></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="account" name="account" value="" maxLength="30" autofocus autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please enter username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 45px;"><img src="https://resource.solarcloudsystem.com/WManage/web/img/format/icons/key.png?v=2.0.4.4" height="16" /></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" name="password" maxLength="50" placeholder="Please enter password">
                </div>
                
                
                
                
            </div>
            
            <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <a href="forgetPassword" style="float: right; color: inherit;" target="_blank">Forget password?</a>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" style="width: calc(100% - 115px); margin-right: 5px;">Sign in</button>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" style="width: 106px;" href="/WManage/web/register">Register</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                
                    <a href="/WManage/web/login/viewDemoPlant?customCompany=" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" style="width: calc(100% - 115px); margin-right: 5px;">Visit demo station</a>
                
                
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-default" style="width: 106px;" href="/WManage/web/warranty/register">Warranty</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my python code with all the various different ways I have tried so far to click the button. The username and password are just dummy code in this sample.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://eu.luxpowertek.com/WManage/web/login')


username = "uyuytuyreue745@mygmail.com"
password = "kinghferyrt"

# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element("id", "account").send_keys(username)
# find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element("id", "password").send_keys(password)
# click login button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("(//button[contains(text(),'Sign In')])[2]"));
```

So the actual submit button has no ID and this is where I think I am getting confues will all the different ways of selecting it like by Selector, By XPATH by.xxxxx etc

**Sign in**

Any help would be most appreciated, also it appears that the code syntax of selenium has changed over the years as many code samples I have found do not work any more like driver.find_element_by_xpath which is now (I believe) driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xxxx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Selenium expert, but here's what I think is happening. Updating as I go along…

`driver.find_element(By.XPath, 'Sign In'.Click())` fails for two reasons:

- The string "Sign In" is not an XPath.
- You're trying to call `.Click()` on a string. You need to instead [call it on the *response* from `find_element`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350625/96588).\
- The method name is `click`, all lower case.

`driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@href='../cgi-bin/cartReset']")[1].click()`:

- There's no `href` attribute with an exact value of `../cgi-bin/cartReset`, so this can't match anything.
- Tries to click the *second* element. Python lists are zero-indexed, and you probably wanted `[0]`.

`driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//form[@type='Submit']").click()`:

- The XPath would match a `<form>` element with an attribute `type="Submit"`. But the `type="Submit"` attribute is on the *button,* not the form.

`driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-lg btn-success").click()`:

- I don't think the class name selector takes a string with *multiple* classes like this.

`driver.find_element(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).submit();`:

- You don't have any `input` elements with `type="submit"`, only a `button` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can uniquely identify the button using the element type alongside the
class.

[image]

You can then use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn-success").click()
```